# Attach a new Directive to an Existing one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

This is the function which I use for creating a new `SVG` element:

```
makeSvg = function (tag, attrs) {
    var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}
```

And the usage is really simple:

```
var result = makeSvg("my-directive", { "data-attr": "val" });
$compile(result)($scope);
```

This code is working properly but the problem is I want to add an another directive to the produced directive. The value of `result` before `compile` is:

```
<my-directive data-attr="val"></my-directive>
```

Which is an SVG element, so I can't deal with it like a string. I want to create something like this:

```
<my-directive data-attr="val" another-directive></my-directive>
```

After that I'll call `compile` to produce the desired result, but I don't know how create the directive.

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking. What part of `create directive` is the problem?

Comment: @charlietfl I've mentioned that what I want to do! add 'another-directive' to the 'my-directive' is my problem. It's really clear, isn't it?!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear and that's why nobody is responding. WHat have you tried that isn't working is maybe a better way to look at it

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your suggestion but I've tried to clarify as well as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it with an empty string to your attrs object at your call of `makeSvg` will work.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/q0hcxaav/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .directive('myDir', myDirective)
 .directive('anotherDirective', anotherDirective)
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
}

function anotherDirective() {
 return {
     link: function(scope, element) {
         console.log('another directive added');
        }
    }
}

function myDirective($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
     link: function(scope, element) {
         var result = makeSvg("my-directive", { "data-attr": "val", "another-directive": ""});
   var compiled = $compile(result)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(compiled);
        }
    };
    
    function makeSvg(tag, attrs) {
        var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
        for (var k in attrs)
            el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
        return el;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <my-dir></my-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't know why I couldn't solve it!